# Is there a resource that lists the quantity of active transposons for various species?

Tags: dna, resource-recommendation

I read the thesis that transposons are a major factor in human aging. To study that thesis I want to see how the count of active transposons differs by species. Is there an existing database or study that lists active transposon count by species?

Comment: https://mobilednajournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13100-019-0150-y

Comment: RepetDB (linked by Maximilian) and [Dfam](https://www.dfam.org/) are both good databases for TE sequences and lineages, though I think determining which are active is a harder question, especially since [TEs are highly polymorphic within a population](https://www.pnas.org/content/100/9/5280).  A great place to start would be [this recent review of eukaryotic transposable elements](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-genet-040620-022145); see Fig 3, in particular, for a wonderful graphic giving the distribution and genome percentage of different TE classes across eukaryotes.

Comment: Also be aware that the 'density' of transposons can vary hugely within a species — one [example is in maize](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5944910/), where high latitude cultivars are selected for smaller genome sizes (to allow shorter generation times) and consequently have fewer transposons.